# How to add a button (Add-in) to Outlook using Python

Tags: python, winapi, outlook

I'm looking the way to build an AddIn for Outlook with Python that add a button to the toolbar that has a behavior (doesn't matter). 
I've searched around and didn't found anything. The only things I've found are backend, no GUI.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could study the source for the SpamBayes outlook addin:

- http://spambayes.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/spambayes/trunk/spambayes/Outlook2000/addin.py?revision=3243&view=markup

which used "Spam" and "Not Spam" buttons.  (Search for _AddControl function.)

General info on the addin here:

- http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/windows.html

Comment: I thought it didn't have. Thanks for the heads up, appreciated.